# Only showing one pin on the map from my array

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mapkit

I am having trouble showing pins on a map loading coordinates, title and subtitle from parse.com.
Here is my code. Is there any logical wrong? I get only the third row in the db showing, instead of all five that I have at the parse.com.

```
             for(int i = 0; i<objects.count; i++)

             {
                 int raknare = 1;
                 raknare++;

                 PFObject *tempObject = [kundUppgifter objectAtIndex:raknare];

                 PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [tempObject objectForKey:@"CLAT"];
                 PFGeoPoint *geoPoint2 = (PFGeoPoint *)geoPoint;

                 NSString *cname = @"CNAME";
                 NSString *ctown = @"CTOWN";

                 kundUppgifter = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

                 objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cname,ctown,geoPoint,nil];

                 NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];





                     Annotation * myAnn;
                     myAnn = [[Annotation alloc]init];
                     CLLocationCoordinate2D location;

                     double longitude;
                     double latitude;

                     latitude = geoPoint2.latitude;
                     longitude = geoPoint2.longitude;

                     location.latitude = latitude;
                     location.longitude = longitude;

                     geoPoint.latitude = latitude;
                     geoPoint.longitude = longitude;


                     myAnn.coordinate = location;
                     myAnn.title = [tempObject objectForKey:@"CNAME"];
                     myAnn.subtitle = [tempObject objectForKey:@"CTOWN"];



                     [locations addObject:myAnn];

                     [self.myMapView addAnnotations:locations];




                     NSLog(@"geopoint is a pfobject with latitude %f, and longitude %f      kundnamn %@,stad %@,", latitude, longitude, cname, ctown);
                     NSLog(@"%@", cname);
                     NSLog(@"%@", objects);




                }

        }

     }];
```

Happy if you can help!

Comment: Please fix your indentation and dangling braces/brackets.

Comment: You are initialising your variables inside your for loop, so you will always end up with raknare set to 2 (i.e. the 3rd element) but your code is a mess - you are accessing a different array to that which is driving your loop and you are modifying the `objects` array inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11,I just commented out the "objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cname,ctown,geoPoint,nil];" and…. its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i<objects.count; i++)
{   
    int raknare = 1;
    raknare++;
    PFObject *tempObject = [kundUppgifter objectAtIndex:raknare];
}
```

This code inside of your loop will make raknare == 2 every iteration of the loop. You want to use the i variable you set to pull from -objectAtIndex: like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<objects.count; i++)
{   
    // This gives you a different object each iteration of the loop
    PFObject *tempObject = [kundUppgifter objectAtIndex:i];

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you guys!!! I am extremely happy! By changing the things as you told me Joel Bell and also as Paulw11 told me: I just commented out the "objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cname,ctown,geoPoint,nil];" and…. its working! This was awesome. And SLawson I will change the brackets in my next program to normal. Just found it more easy to see in my way. But I suppose it is better to follow the way it should be. Have a nice day!